# Accuracу PC emulation from image that will be installed on a virtual machine VMWare

Tags: vmware

I have a backup image of an engineering station that has licensed software.
When I restore this image on the virtual machine VMWare, the licenses of software will be expired because the hardware ID of the new PC is different.
Can I emulate the hardware part saved PC with VMWare or that is impossible?

Comment: The virtual machine is a different machine (I use VMware) and so you will need to ask the software vendor how to proceed.

Comment: Do you how the hardware is is calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the software itself how it determines whether it is the same machine. Usually it could be using hardware information from motherboard (e.g., various controllers), hard drives, etc. VMware is not designed to mimic a PC in such a way. Also, it is usually not compliant to the license if you have two machines (i.e., a physical machine and a virtual machine) that attempts to appear as the same.

If you plan to just use the machine image as a backup, then you should leave it as is and it would still work when you recover it to your physical machine.

If you plan to give up your physical machine, or set up two machines, you will need to transfer your license or purchase another one. Contact your software vendor for this.